# Extract numbers from alphanumeric string

Tags: r, dataset

I have a column in a data set that indicates the amount of years each person in the sample has had so far. But the data is "1 year in school", "2 years in school", "3 years in school"... but I want it to be just 1, 2, 3...
I know it seems simple and it must be, but I'm probably not phrasing it correctly so I can't find it on google.

Haven't really tried anything cause never used R before.

Comment: It sounds like you want to extract the number part from some text. One simple way to do this is `readr::parse_number`, for instance `df <- data.frame(foo =  "1 year in school", "2 years in school", "3 years in school"); df$bar = readr::parse_number(df$foo)`